# Add Comma to the result values in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to add comma (, ) if I have this code in jquery:

```
var title = !this.multiple ? selectedItems[0] : selectedItems.join(", ");

            //If this is multi select, and the selectText type is count, the show 1 of 2 selected etc..
            if (this.multiple && this.options.selectedTextFormat.indexOf('count') > -1) {
                var max = this.options.selectedTextFormat.split(">");
                var notDisabled = this.options.hideDisabled ? ':not([disabled])' : '';
                if ( (max.length>1 && selectedItems.length > max[1]) || (max.length==1 && selectedItems.length>=2)) {
                    title = this.options.countSelectedText.replace('{0}', selectedItems.length).replace('{1}', this.$element.find('option:not([data-divider="true"]):not([data-hidden="true"])'+notDisabled).length);
                }
             }

            //If we dont have a title, then use the default, or if nothing is set at all, use the not selected text
            if (!title) {
                title = this.options.title != undefined ? this.options.title : this.options.noneSelectedText;
            }

            this.$newElement.find('.filter-option').html(title);
```

In the `dropdown` I select multiple values and they will be join by (, ) like this: 'Compositor, Designer, Graphic Artist' but when I get the values and post it in the table above the values became 'CompositorDesignerGraphicArtics'

In the jquery code how can I insert comma. So that when I get the values it should be like the same in the dropdown.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle ?

Comment: I have a long code. The jquery I used is the bootstrap-select.js